# flask sqalchemy ForeignKey is always null

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

See the code below. Why is the parkplatz_id ForeignKey always null?
I tried many configurations for the relation between the tables "Bilder"/"Buchung" and "Parkplatz" but the ForeignKey "parkplatz_id" inside "Bilder"/"Buchung" is always null.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base import UUID
from . import db

class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    vorname = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    nachname = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    mobil = db.Column(db.BigInteger)

class Parkplatz(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "parkplatz"
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    lat = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    lng = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    anzahl = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    art = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    platz = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    kamera = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    zaun = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    licht = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    security = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    info = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    preis = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    # buchungen = db.relationship("Buchung", backref="vermieter")
    # fotos = db.relationship("Bilder", backref="vermieter")

class Bilder(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bilder"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    parkplatz_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("parkplatz.id"), nullable=False, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    foto = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    parkplatz = db.relationship('Parkplatz', primaryjoin='Bilder.parkplatz_id == Parkplatz.id', backref='bilder')

class Buchung(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "buchung"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    parkplatz_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("parkplatz.id"), nullable=False, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    start_datum = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    start_zeit = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    end_datum = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    end_zeit = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    parkplatz = db.relationship('Parkplatz', primaryjoin='Buchung.parkplatz_id == Parkplatz.id', backref='buchungen')
```

Comment: How do you fill Bilder/Buchung?

Comment: I fill it with `from .models import Bilder` an then `new_bild = Bilder(email=current_user.id, foto=img.read(), name=file_name)`. Since parkplatz_id should match the id from the Parkplatz Table I don't declare it when calling Bilder.

Comment: you need to create a method which will give you the parkplatz_id and after that you can fill it in Bilder(email=current_user.id, foto=img.read(), name=file_name,parkplatz_id=method_name)

Comment: @Dori Ok, thank you. But why must I manually insert the parkplatz_id? I thought because of the ForeignKey this Table row will be graped from the Parkplatz.id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Parkplatz() class, which is the parent of the Bilder() class

```
new_parkplatz = Parkplatz("pass in all required values")
```

After creating the parent, which can be reused as often as you want.
You can then create the Bilder() child and pass in the parent (Parkplatz)

```
new_bilder = Bilder(
    email=current_user.id,
    foto=img.read(),
    parkplatz=new_parkplatz
)
```

Specifying the parkplatz which is the name given to the relationship() with the Parkplatz() created in the Bilder()

```
parkplatz = db.relationship("Parkplatz", primaryjoin="", backref="")
```

will give it a parent (new_parkplatz) to inherit from, and now the parkplatz_id will have the new_parkplatz id

But if the parkplatz is not specified in the new_bilder the parkplatz_id will return Null, because there is no parent to inherit the id from

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the ‍‍`new_bilder` like so:

```py
## make sure to set the parkplatz in the Bilder class(child) to the Parkplatz() class(parent) you want to get the parkplatz_id from

new_bilder = Bilder(
    email=current_user.id,
    foto=omg.read(),
    name=file_name,
    parkplatz="pass in the Parkplatz() class you want to get the parkplatz_id from"
    )
```

The `new_bilder` child has to have the parent class passed in as the name given to the child `relationship()`, which is

```py
parkplatz = db.relationship('Parkplatz', primaryjoin=Bilder.parkplatz_id == Parkplatz.id', backref='bilder')
```

If the `parkplatz` is not specified in the `new_bilder` there will be no parent to inherit the `parkplatz_id` from, so it will return *null*.